# Neo4J (3.4.8) rejects simple CREATE CONSTRAINT Cypher command. No idea how to proceed

Tags: neo4j

I have started learning NEO4J and thought I was doing well in developing a basic few lines of Cypher, loading in my first CSV successfully.

Then I needed to add uniqueness CONSTRAINTS for nodes, and here is where I hit the wall. The software refuses to accept the command, somehow recognising "I" or "i" in "is UNIQUE" or "IS UNIQUE" as an unexpected character, although I have multiple checked my syntax and retyped MANY times.

Even starting from a completely blank new database, I get this weird error. I found one solution by renaming the node name "Investor" with "F_Investor" but then the problem returns with the next entry (for "Issuer").

I attach screen shots which should help to understand the problem.

[1] -- top of screen at command line, the "In" in "Investor" has been highlighted green?

[2] -- command line, this time the "Is" in "Issuer" has been highlighted.

[3] -- here, I have renamed as "R_Issuer" but then it finds an error further down the line...

[4] -- a solution that works this time (why not last time?) by renaming as "F_Investor"

Any thoughts on this would be highly welcome as I am disheartened!

Thanks!

[1] https://pasteboard.co/HHzMHLa.png

[2] https://pasteboard.co/HHzNg1c.png

[3] https://pasteboard.co/HHzO7Qw.png

[4] https://pasteboard.co/HHzOSvl.png

Comment: PS -- I am using Windows 7 (yes maybe thats the problem :/ ) and Firefox, running NEO4j community 3.4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one thing in common with all of the commands that failed: You use a `:` in your assert instead of `.`.

`... ASSERT i:name IS UNIQUE`
is incorrect and is the reason for the syntax error.

`... ASSERT i.name IS UNIQUE`
is correct, note that we're using dot notation for signifying a property of a node.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for taking the time to show me that. I cant believe I missed it! What a noob! "May sweet meats and heavenly jewels rain upon thee" (from my fav. Brit comedy)...